# Build an .exe that runs without C++ Redistributable Package

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, clr

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 C# (my interface) and Visual Studio 2017 Community C++ (.exe who is called during interface process)

I need to export my project to others PC and if they do not have Visual Studio installed they are missing some dll. I know there is an option to select to free from this kind of things : "C++ 2015 Redistributable Package". Does anyone knows how I can solve this on VS 2019 and VS 2017, otherwise I will be forced to add an installer with my files.

Thanks

Comment: My advice is to use an Installer to properly install your executable and install the required redistributable if needed.

Comment: @drescherjm do you have a link or a short explanation of what i should add ? I don't know this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found the solution to whom it may concern, in visual studio 2017 (my C++ code) i did this :

1. Right-click your project in “Solution Explorer”, select “Properties” from the popped menu. Then the “Property Pages” dialog opens.
2. In the opened “Property Pages” dialog, select “Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library” , set its value to “Multi-threaded (/MT)” or “Multi-threaded Debug(/MTd)”.

Comment: That's how you do it, indeed, except you don't want to distribute debug builds (/MTd). Those are meant for you to debug on your development machine.